# What does this documentation syntax mean at MDN for a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm learning JavaScript through ["Eloquent JavaScript"](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) manual and now I'm doing exercises from chapter 5 ["High-Order Functions"](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html). One of the functions this chapter introduces you is "**reduce**". I understand how it works, my problem comes up when I try to understand its definition at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Examples). I don't understand syntax definition it gives:

```
arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])
```

This syntax sections is followed by the section called Parameters. These are:

- callback

  - previousValue
  - currentValue
  - index
  - array
- *initialValue (optional)*

What I don't understand is what do those square brackets and the comma mean? Because when I see square brackets immediately I think in arrays. And why is just `initialValue` in the definition and not the others parameters? Why there is no space between square brackets and `callback`?

Because below there are two examples:

Example 1

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
    return previousValue + currentValue;
});
```

Example 2

```
var total = [0, 1, 2, 3].reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
});
// total == 6
```

and I don't know how do they fit into the definition.

Thanks

Comment: APIs commonly use brackets to indicate optional parameters. It's not a language feature.

Comment: The `square brackets` mean that the parameter is optional, hence the `,` is just seperating the `parameters`, like if you would make use of it the function would be `arr.reduce(callback, initialValue)`. As poster above mentioned it's not a `language` feature but the way of `documenting` it.

Comment: English is not my language and I thought that the title doesn't mean that the syntax is JavaScript. I'll, fix it. And I still don't know why then is callback in the definition and not the rest of variables. And thanks by the way ;)

Comment: Ah ok. That's because for `callback` you refer to a `function` which has the parameters `previousValue`, `currentValue`, `index` and `array`. The `intialValue` is an optional `parameter` for the `reduce` function itself. If you look into the examples it says `.reduce(function(callback params))`. An `anonymous function` is specified in the `reduce` function.

Comment: Ok. I thought that those parameters were for reduce and not for the callback. Now it's clear. Thank you very much ;)

Comment: @Francodi, just one thing more. So, in the second example, `index`, `currentValue`, etc.  are internally defined and `reduce` calculate internally their values? And for callback, parameter names are reserved names?

Comment: @Noob_Number_1 You've copied the infomation from the page incorrectly. Under Parameters, under `callback`, there is no `initialValue`.

Comment: @torazaburo can you explain me this question: in the second example, index, currentValue, etc. are internally defined and reduce calculate internally their values? And for callback, parameter names are reserved names?

Comment: No, they're not reserved names. They just describe what the parameter does. You could use x, y, and z if you preferred.

Answer (score 3):

It's usually a convention for API documentations to use `[]` to denote optional parameters. However, the `[]` is not part of the syntax on usage. It's just documentation convention.

Comment: Thanks, I read that at the MDN article. What I don't understand is why is just `callback` at the definition and not the rest of `reduce` variables.

Comment: @Noob_Number_1 `callback` isn't optional. Try running reduce and not providing `callback` and the operation will throw an error.

Comment: This is incorrect. If `initialValue` is omitted, the first iteration of `reduce` is **not** provided `null` as an argument. Instead, the *first two elements of the array* are passed as `previousValue` and `currentValue`.

Answer (score 1):

As already explained in other answers, the parameters inside of the "[]" are optional. Regarding the question as to why the "other parameters" (i.e. previousValue etc.) are not there, those are parameters to `callback` and not to `reduce`. So `callback` will receive those arguments on each run of `reduce`.